# Cross apply with JSON array

Tags: sql, arrays, json, sql-server, t-sql

I have table stored data is in below format -

[image]

Now, I want to write a SQL query to represent this data in below format-

[image]

Note: Data stored in Product column is JSON array.

Comment: Add the code you've tried to your question, which I would expect to use `OPENJSON`.

Comment: "Now I want" isn't a question; what are you asking here? What have you tried? Why didn't it work? Images of data don't help us help you; take the time to provide data in a consumable format if you want to volunteers here to take the time to help you.

Comment: [Sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852/) is better presented as [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 18):

You need two additional `APPLY` operators with two different `OPENJSON()` calls. First call is with default schema and the result is a table with columns `key`, `value` and `type`. The second call is with explicit schema with the appropriate columns, defined using the `WITH` clause:

Table:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
   CustomerID int,
   City nvarchar(50),
   Product nvarchar(max)
)
INSERT INTO Data
   (CustomerID, City, Product)
VALUES
   (1, N'Delhi', N'[{"Products": [{"Id": "1", "Name": "TV"}, {"Id": "2", "Name": "Laptop"}]}]'),
   (2, N'Bamgalore', N'[{"Products": [{"Id": "1", "Name": "TV"}, {"Id": "2", "Name": "Laptop"}, {"Id": "3", "Name": "Mobile"}]}]')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT d.CustomerID, j2.Id, j2.Name
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(d.Product, '$') j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value], '$.Products') WITH (
   Id nvarchar(10) '$.Id',
   Name nvarchar(50) '$.Name'
) j2
```

Result:

```
----------------------
CustomerID  Id  Name
----------------------
1           1   TV
1           2   Laptop
2           1   TV
2           2   Laptop
2           3   Mobile
```

Answer (score 3):

You can apply the arrays, to get to the object values.

```
SELECT t.CustomerId, a.*
FROM YourCustomerProductsTable t
OUTER APPLY
(
   SELECT
     [ProductId] = CAST(JSON_VALUE(obj.value,'$.Id') AS INT)
   , [Product] = JSON_VALUE(obj.value,'$.Name')
   FROM OPENJSON(t.Product) AS arr
   CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(arr.value, '$.Products') AS obj
) a;
```